# interp2 from MATLAB to R

Tags: r, matlab, interpolation, linear-interpolation

I am using the `interp2` function in MATLAB and need to transfer it to R.

In MATLAB's `interp2(X,Y,V,Xq,Yq)`, X and Y are allowed to be either vectors or matrices - in my case they are matrices. However, R's functions `interp2` and `interp` only accept vectors. I have also tried `interp.surface.grid`, but cannot get it working. What might also be important here is that I specify all the five arguments of the MATLAB's function. My objective is simply to obtain the same results in R with the same input.

Any suggestions how to solve this issue are much appreciated!

Comment: Are your `X` and `Y` regular? If so you can probably use [R's `interp2`](https://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/pracma/html/interp2.html), just only use the `x` and `y` from one row/column.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Although the output format is different - R outputs a vector, while MATLAB outputs a matrix of size determined by function's arguments (even though the same arguments are passed in R). But a quick rearranging solves the issue.